# Foreign key constraint fails on existing key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In an existing Laravel project we encounter a vague problem when inserting a new record in our mysql database. The workflow is like this, whenever we create a new company, we also create users which belong to that company, somehow when submitting the new user, the foreign key constraint fails while we are 100% certain that key exists, and that we have the right key in hands.

Even stranger is that sometimes the creation goes well,and we can insert many users after that without any problems.

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction on how to proceed or debug this further.

EDIT: I've added some code, i don't think there is anything special here, except for the nullable on the foreignkey. This is a relative new addition, because not every user belongs to a company, so that's why I added that one.

I think the question would be: how can a foreign key fail, when you know (verify) that this key exists, is the right key and is 100% sure of the right type.

```
    $company = new Company();
    $company->fill($request->all());
    $company->showLicence = (int)$request->get('showLicence');

    $company->save();

    //create a zero-user for each company to be able to login support    staff
    $user = new User();

    $user->name = "user";

    $user->password = bcrypt('password');
    $user->company_id = $company->id;
    $user->save();

//user migration
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('profession');
        $table->integer('productivity');
        $table->date('birthDay');
        $table->boolean('active');
        $table->string('standardCalendar');
        $table->string('calendar');
        $table->integer('department')->unsigned();

        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

        $table->foreign('company_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });

    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('companyName');
        $table->string('street');
        $table->string('zipcode');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('fax');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('website');
        $table->string('logo');
        $table->string('taxNumber');
        $table->string('welcome');
        $table->boolean('showLicence');
    });
```

Comment: You need to provide code.

Comment: with the code is better

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: code of migrations...company & user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your migration code, the foreign key `company_id` on `users` actually refers to itself, not the `company` table. Change `->on('users')` into `->on('companies')`.

As an additional tip, if your `Company` Eloquent model has a `users` relation (a method returning `$this->hasMany('User');`), you can insert the new user as follows:

```
$user = $company->users()->create([
    'name' => 'user',
    'password' => bcrypt('password'),
]);
```

Comment: That's really stupid, thanks for spotting that one Joost. Luckily this was still dev. code, but it explains partially why the current dev insertions fail. (it does not explain the ones that worked : /,

Comment: @Analogue no problem! So does this resolve the issue, and if so, can you accept this answer? :)

Comment: Well yes and no, but your answer pushed me in the right direction. I just finished my research. The case is as follows, the migration whit the error you spotted was ran yesterday and rolled back later. And that's where the problem occured, somehow the rollback did not change the relation back to it's original state. But was left blank (how is that even possible?)

Since you gave the right push and saved me hours of work, i'll accept your answer! :)